# Angular Nebular Chat only for one Module and Component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, nebular

I want to integrate only the NbChat into my project.
At first I just tried to integrate it normally in my whole project, but I got following error as soon as I try to use components with typescript logic (in this case logging in), when the `NbThemeModule.forRoot({ name: 'corporate' })` is stated as an import in the `app.module` and when the `app.component.html` is wrapped in NbLayout:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.container is undefined
_createContainer@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:80244:9
getContainerElement@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:178191:18
_createHostElement@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:180093:32
create@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:180060:27
_createOverlay@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:112117:30
_attach@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:112026:33
openFromComponent@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:111963:21
open@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:111991:21
login/<@http://localhost:4200/main.js:7096:68
__awaiter/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:167019:71
ZoneAwarePromise@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1317:33
__awaiter@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:167015:12
login@http://localhost:4200/main.js:7084:75.....
```

Since this breaks everything in the Application, I though of placing the whole chat in a component exported by a sub module which exports it, and imports

> ```
> NbThemeModule.forRoot({ name: 'corporate' }),
> NbLayoutModule,
> NbEvaIconsModule,
> NbChatModule
> ```

Vice Versa I import the self written ChatModule then in the `app.module.ts`.

Since the same error happens for other people when Nebular Chat Components are not wrapt in nb-layout, so here you can see that the Chat Component is wrapped as follows.:

```
<nb-layout>
   <nb-layout-column>
    <nb-chat title="Drag & Drop chat" size="medium">
        <nb-chat-message *ngFor="let msg of messages"
                         [type]="msg.type"
                         [message]="msg.text"
                         [reply]="msg.reply"
                         [sender]="msg.user.name"
                         [date]="msg.date"
                         [files]="msg.files"
                         [avatar]="msg.user.avatar">
        </nb-chat-message>
        <nb-chat-form (send)="sendMessage($event)" [dropFiles]="true"></nb-chat-form>
      </nb-chat>
   </nb-layout-column>
</nb-layout>
```

For some reason I still get the same error.
Help is appreciated.

**Update1:**

While debugging with Chrome I got more specific Error Codes:

```
core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined
at NbOverlayContainerAdapter._createContainer (index.js:2116)
at NbOverlayContainerAdapter.getContainerElement (overlay.js:735)
at Overlay._createHostElement (overlay.js:2637)
at Overlay.create (overlay.js:2604)
at MatDialog._createOverlay (dialog.js:673)
at MatDialog.open (dialog.js:632)
at ActivejobsComponent.openJobCreation (activejobs.component.ts:72)
at ActivejobsComponent_div_1_Template_button_click_5_listener (activejobs.component.html:9)
at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:14309)
at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:14344)
```

While more testing, it seems like that only Importing NbTheme in any submodule, causes a conflict with all overlays (MatDialog, MatMenu, MatSnackbar, MatSideNav) of Angular Material.

Comment: did you resolve this by any chance?

Comment: the only way I found out to resolve it was to wrap the whole app.component.html in <nb-layout> and made it via css as impactless as possible. There where still conflicts with some MatSnackbars occasionally, at the affected positions, I replaced them with nbToasts. Since it is not a "real" solution, I put it here in the comments

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when using NbThemeModule with MatMenuModule, and resolved it with passing

```
...NbThemeModule.forRoot().providers, NbThemeModule
```

into providers of chat component instead using it on whole the project. So it's worked only on the page where component used.

Also i put

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    document.body.classList.remove('nb-theme-default');
});
```

into ngOnInit in the app.component to disable global nebular styles and use this class only where i use the chat.

Answer (score 0):

@Marc

Thanks to @0vC4

I've created a solution :

https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/1663#issuecomment-1184924290

#### 1.  add this line in imports of `app.module.ts`

```
imports: [  
    NbThemeModule.forRoot({ name: 'default' }),
]
```

#### 2.`app.component.html` ;

```
<nb-layout>
    <nb-layout-column>
        <main>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </main>
    </nb-layout-column>
</nb-layout>
```

#### 3. Make sure that the following code is part of `styles.scss` ;

```
@use 'themes' as *;
@use '@nebular/theme/styles/globals' as *;
@include nb-install() {
  @include nb-theme-global();
};
```

#### 4. `themes.scss` ;

```
@forward '@nebular/theme/styles/theming';
@use '@nebular/theme/styles/theming' as *;
@use '@nebular/theme/styles/themes/default';

$nb-themes: nb-register-theme((
  // add your variables here like:
  // color-primary-100: #f2f6ff,
  // color-primary-200: #d9e4ff,
), default, default);
```

#### 5. in  `app.component.ts` add this piece of code in `ngOnInit()`

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
          document.body.classList.remove('nb-theme-default');
      });
  }
```

- *This will remove the nebular theme from all the app.*

#### 6. in the component you want to apply the theme add this in `ngOnInit()`

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    document.body.classList.add('nb-theme-default');
  }
```

- *This will add the nebular theme @ the current component.*